# Why does my c++ code run fine on Windows 7 but crashes on Windows 8?

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-7

Ok, I added the following code to a mod menu for a game and everything works fine for me in Windows 7. But when I send it to my friend on Windows 8, he tries to select a button (which calls the GetClients() function) and the game just crashes. Any idea why?

```
char* playerNames[31] = {};
int getUID(char* pName)
{
int i = 0;
while (i < 31) {
    char* pNamesec = (char*)PLAYER::GET_PLAYER_NAME((Player)(i));
    if (pNamesec == pName) {
        return i;
    }
    //else { break; }
    i++;
}
}
char* getPnameAt(int id) {
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    if (i == id) {
        return (char*)PLAYER::GET_PLAYER_NAME((Player)(i));

    }
}
}
void GetClients()
{
playerNames[31] = {};
int i = 0;
while (i < 100) {
    char* pName = (char*)PLAYER::GET_PLAYER_NAME((Player)(i));
    if (wcslen((WCHAR*)pName) > 3) {
        if (getUID(pName) == i) {
            playerNames[i] = pName;
        } else {
            getPnameAt(i);
        }
    }
    i++;
}
i = 0;
}
```

Error message that pops up says:
CORE: An exception occurred while executing modmenu.asi, press ok to continue

Comment: Read much more about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Compile with all warnings & debug info, and learn how to use the debugger. BTW, your code is not genuine C++, you should use C++ types (e.g. `std::string`) and containers (e.g. `std::map`, `std::vector`).

Answer (score 3):

You have created an array of length 31. So you can access array playerName from index 0 to index 30. In GetClients()

```
playerNames[31] = {}; //Observe this line
while (i < 100) {
  // Indexes greater than 30 are being used to access playerNames array
}
```

31 or beyond is not a valid index for playerNames array and you are getting undefined behavior.

So if you want to add in playerNames in runtime. Below is the small example that might help you..

```
int main()
{
     vector<string> playerNames;
     playerNames.push_back("XYZ");
     playerNames.push_back("ABC");
     // To access from vector
     vector<string>::iterator itr = vec.begin();
     for(;itr!=vec.end();itr++)
     {
        cout<<*itr<<endl;
     }
}
```

Read more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: Should I make it 32? What would be a valid index?

Comment: @QuavoOs: the problem is that `playerNames[31]` does not match `while (i < 100)`. If you want really want to work with a fixed number of maximum number of players, define a constant **at one and only one place** in your code and reuse it at every place which depends on this number. However, if possible I would avoid to use such fixed numbers. Utilize a `std::vector` instead of fixed size arrays whenever possible, then you can easily add exactly the number of elements to the collection you need.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer valid indexes are from 0 to 30 so total length of array will be 31. So 32 is not valid and might face problem also I missed that while loop.... so as far as I understand you want to increase playerNames at runtime... if thats the case you should use vector...Making few changes in answer...

Comment: Ok Doc I don't think that was the issue since it worked on windows 7 fine, I also made the indexes valid and that didn't work.

Comment: And HadeS can you help me better understand how the vector works? I'm pretty sure that is what I need to fix this, and how I originally went about making the players list but didn't understand how it worked that well.

Comment: @QuavoOs I don't know how can I help you more in this... I have showed you how to add element and retrieve them from vector.... I think it would be better if you try it yourself... try code in the link i gave..